# To omit double quote and pass the values

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a string array which has values i want to pass values in a series chart .But my actual result it pass values in a string format as "1,2,3" But it should pass values like 1,2,3.Pls help me to do this

```
string[] Stocks = StockDetails.ToArray();
            string s = string.Join(",", Stocks);
var series = new Collection<Serie>();
  series.Add(new Serie { name = "Current Stock", data = new string[] { s } });
```

The values should  be like

```
 series.Add(new Serie { name = "André", data = new object[] { 4, 15, 5, 17, 14 }, });
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `Stocks` in the first place?

```
string[] Stocks = StockDetails.ToArray();
var series = new Collection<Serie>();
series.Add(new Serie { name = "Current Stock", data = Stocks });
```

For the sake of completeness, if you have a comma separated string like `"1,2,3"`, you can use `String.Split` to get a `string[]`:

```
string[] nums = "1,2,3".Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you are having data like -

```
 string []Stocks={"1,2,3","2,4,5","3","4"};
```

so you need to split data as follows to obtain string array -

```
 string []Stocks={"1,2,3","2,4,5","3","4"};
        string temp_stocks = string.Join(",", Stocks);

        string[] splited_temp_stocks;

        splited_temp_stocks = temp_stocks.Split(',');

        var series = new Collection<Serie>();
        series.Add(new Serie { name = "Current Stock", data = splited_temp_stocks });
```